# How to return an input and set the value of another input on a form based on the first input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to javascript so I apologize if this is a very basic question.

I am building (Drag & drop) forms for user input of data through a website. I have two time inputs (`STARTTIME` and `TESTTIME`) that are in `HH:MM` format.  I need to display the time 15 minutes after `STARTTIME` (15MIN) and the number of minutes that have passed between `STARTTIME` AND `TESTTIME` (`TIMEDIF`).

The website provides the drag & drop form editor and has a field where I can add javascript to the form.

I've figured out how to take string inputs of "`HH:MM`" and output the values I need.

I am struggling with extracting the input from the two time fields (`STARTTIME` and `TESTTIME`) and writing to the 15MIN and `TIMEDIF` fields.

For returning the input from the form, I've tried using:

```
var atime = $("#" + STARTTIME + "input");
var ttime = $("#"+ TESTTIME + "input");
```

//-or-

```
var atime = $("div[id=STARTTIME] input"); 
var ttime = $("div[id=TESTTIME] input");
```

//and for setting the 15MIN and `TIMEDIF` variables

```
$("div[id=15MIN] input").val(tqtime);
$("div[id=TIMEDIF] input").val(difftime);
```

//`tqtime` and `difftime` are in "`HH:MM`" and number format, respectively and are calculated from `atime` and `ttime`.

I have tested the output of the code from `atime` and `ttime` defined as "`HH:MM`" strings to tqtime and `difftime`, which has been successful.

However, all variables are undefined when used with the form, leading me to believe that I'm not returning the input correctly.

Comment: The input values are stored in `value` property. In jquery use `.val()` to access the input value i:e `$("#" + STARTTIME + "input").val()`.

Comment: Format and read [mcve], thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call $("someselector"), what you get is a jQuery element. This is more than just the value of the input, and thus you must actually call a function to get that value. With jQuery, you use the `.val()` method to achieve this. Assume that `"#" + STARTTIME + input" and "#" + TESTTIME + "input"` are ids of `input` elements, getting the values would look like this:

```
var atime = $("#" + STARTTIME + "input").val();
var ttime = $("#" + TESTTIME + "input").val();
```